# Strong-type OpenIdConnectOptions for aspnet core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to understand How can we utilize the strong-type when constructing the OpenIDConnectOptions.

I know we can implement strong type for appsettings and other items using POCO class and IOptions implementation and accessing those from Controller constructor But here, my issue is before the controller part. At run-time starup it fails.

To Start with, I have startup.configureservice with:

```
services.AddAzureADOpenIDAuthentication(Configuration);
```

I have Extension method for IServiceCollection for AddAzureADOpenIDAuthentication like:

```
services.Configure<AzureADOptions>(configuration.GetSection("Authentication:AzureAd"));

        services.AddSingleton<IOptionsMonitor<OpenIdConnectOptions>, AzureADOpenIdConnectOptionsSetup>();

        services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
        {
            auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            auth.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie().AddOpenIdConnect();

        return services;
```

Finally I have AzureADOpenIdConnectOptionsSetup with the implementation of IOptionsMonitor like below:

```
public class AzureADOpenIdConnectOptionsSetup : IOptionsMonitor<OpenIdConnectOptions>
{
    public OpenIdConnectOptions CurrentValue { get; set; }

    public AzureADOpenIdConnectOptionsSetup(IOptionsMonitor<AzureADOptions> azureADOptions)
    {
        CurrentValue = new OpenIdConnectOptions();

        CurrentValue.ClientId = azureADOptions.CurrentValue.ClientId;
        CurrentValue.Authority = azureADOptions.CurrentValue.Authority;
        CurrentValue.CallbackPath = azureADOptions.CurrentValue.CallbackPath;
    }

    public OpenIdConnectOptions Get(string name)
    {
        return CurrentValue;
    }

    public IDisposable OnChange(Action<OpenIdConnectOptions, string> listener)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

When I run this code, It hit the Constructor and OpenIdConnectOptions Get twice and through the breakpoint at constructor level, I check the settings are correctly transferred from azureADOptions to OpenIdConnectOptions CurrentValue.
Still, I am getting an error message (before I press login, it means startup it self)

> InvalidOperationException: Provide Authority, MetadataAddress, Configuration, or ConfigurationManager to OpenIdConnectOptions

I am not sure, whether I have correctly implemented OpenIdConnectOptions Get(string name) or not.
One more doubt is, How should I implement OnChange(Action listener) to listen the run-time change of appsettings.json

Answer (score 2):

For returning `OpenIdConnectOptions`, you need to initialize ConfigurationManager, and a simple code like below:

```
    public static class AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions
{      
    public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureADOpenIDAuthentication(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        builder.Services.Configure<AzureAdOptions>(configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IOptionsMonitor<OpenIdConnectOptions>, AzureADOpenIdConnectOptionsSetup>();

        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
        {
            auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            auth.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect();
        return builder;
    }

    public class AzureADOpenIdConnectOptionsSetup : IOptionsMonitor<OpenIdConnectOptions>
    {
        public OpenIdConnectOptions CurrentValue { get; set; }
        private IDataProtectionProvider _dataProtectionProvider;

        public AzureADOpenIdConnectOptionsSetup(IOptionsMonitor<AzureAdOptions> azureADOptions,IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider)
        {
            _dataProtectionProvider = dataProtectionProvider;
            CurrentValue = new OpenIdConnectOptions
            {
                ClientId = azureADOptions.CurrentValue.ClientId,
                Authority = $"{azureADOptions.CurrentValue.Instance}{azureADOptions.CurrentValue.TenantId}",
                CallbackPath = azureADOptions.CurrentValue.CallbackPath
            };
        }

        public OpenIdConnectOptions Get(string name)
        {
            OpenIdConnectPostConfigureOptions op = new OpenIdConnectPostConfigureOptions(_dataProtectionProvider);
            op.PostConfigure(name, CurrentValue);
            return CurrentValue;
        }

        public IDisposable OnChange(Action<OpenIdConnectOptions, string> listener)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }        
}
```