# Exeption throw Provide Authority, MetadataAddress, Configuration, or ConfigurationManager to OpenIdConnectOptions

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity

I am using Azure AD authentication and Identity on ASP.NET Core 6. I configured it at Program.cs
[image]
When I run the application this exception is occurs

```
InvalidOperationException: Provide Authority, MetadataAddress, Configuration, or ConfigurationManager to OpenIdConnectOptions
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectOptions.Validate()
```

I understand I have to provide Authority, MetadataAddress, Configuration, or ConfigurationManager to OpenIdConnectOptions but no idea to resolve this.

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I tried with your code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var initialScopes = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');

            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                   .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
           

            services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
    .AddCookie(options => {
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login/";
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = Configuration["oidc:clientid"];
        options.ResponseType = "code";
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.Validate();
    }
    );

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });
           services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
        }
```

**Error:**

```
  System.InvalidOperationException
  Message=Provide Authority, MetadataAddress, Configuration, or ConfigurationManager to OpenIdConnectOptions
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectOptions.Validate()
```

[image]

The cause here is missing configuration of OpenID Connect .As the error states it misses authority, metadata address, configuration in OpenIdConnectOptions.

[image]

To resolve this issue, provide the required information in tht OpenIdConnectOptions .

options.ClientId = Configuration["ClientId"];
options.ClientSecret = Configuration["ClientSecret"];
options.Authority = Configuration["Authority"];
options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

[image]
where client credentials can be fetched from **appsettings.json**:

```
 {
    "AzureAd": {
      "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
      "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid",
      //"Domain": "testthetenant365.onmicrosoft.com",
      "ClientId": "500xxxx06e",
      "TenantId": "fb134080-e4d2-45f4-9562-f3a0c218f3b0",
      "ClientSecret": "xxxxxx",
       "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
    },
```

code:

```
  services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
    .AddCookie(options => {
         options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login/";

    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"];
        options.Authority = Configuration["AzureAd:Authority"];
 
       options.MetadataAddress = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/.well-known/openid-configuration";
        options.ResponseType = "code";
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
 options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.Validate();

    }
    );
```

In case of error ,it must be due to  Authentication builder configuration missing

Install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI

See [c# - Strong-type OpenIdConnectOptions for aspnet core 2.0 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45768232/strong-type-openidconnectoptions-for-aspnet-core-2-0)

Add reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI` in *.csproj

You can use below code for built-in mechanisms:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var initialScopes = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');


            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)

               .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
                   .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                        .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();


            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });
           services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
        }
```

[image]